# A function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equal to its linearization in each point

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

I have a function $P: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. This function satisfies:
$$ P(\vec{x}) = J_P(\vec{x}) \cdot \vec{x}$$
where $\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $J_P$ is the Jacobian of $P$ and "$\cdot$" is
the matrix-vector product. I would rougly describe it as in the title.

I guess that it is a well known property. Do you know what is its name? Can you 
suggest some literature about it, or any known property?

Also, I would like to to know about the symplectic equivalent:
$$ P(\vec{x}) = -\Omega \cdot J_P(\vec{x}) \cdot \Omega \cdot \vec{x}$$
where $\Omega$ defines the symplectic form.

Comment: Aren't all such functions just linear ?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni but the derivative does not exist at zero. I thought the upper condition means differentiable everywhere and that equality holds. If it does not mean that, what are the implied differentiability assumptions for higher $n$.

Comment: I can't work out right now but this is closely related to the equation for homogeneous degree one functions: see "Euler's homogeneous function theorem"

Comment: in fact maybe it is exactly that

Comment: We should take each component of $P$ separately, right? So I see that, if all the $P_i(\vec{x})$ functions are homogeneous, then my condition holds. This shows that my condition does not imply that $P$ is linear, but maybe must have a discontinuity! However, this is the reverse of what I was asking: can you prove that my condition implies that all the components are homogeneous?

Comment: The first PDE is a decoupled system of first order scalar equations, so one may analyse its solutions by the method of characteristics.

Comment: @T_M : can you please write your comment on homogeneous functions as an answer, so that I can mark it as accepted? Although I already got a "rigorously correct" answer, this one looks more helpful for me.

Comment: The characteristic lines for this PDE are just the rays from the origin, and solving the corresponding ODE is exactly the proof of Euler Th.m on homogeneous functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the symplectic case. Let $J$ be the symplectic matrix $J:=\left[ \matrix{ 0 & I_n \\ -I_n & 0 }\right]$. The characteristic lines for the (first order, linear, partial differential, vector) equation 
$$P(x)=-J \,{\rm d}P(x)J x, \qquad x\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}\setminus\{0\},$$
are the solutions of the ODE $\dot \xi=J\xi$, that is circles $\xi(t)=e^{tJ}x_0$. Along these characteristic lines, the equation is 
$\partial_t P(\xi(t))= {\rm d}P(\xi(t))J \xi(t)=JP(\xi(t))$, meaning that $P\circ \xi$ satisfies the same ODE, so that we have that $P(e^{tJ}x)=e^{tJ}P(x)$, for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}\setminus\{0\}$,  is a necessary and sufficient condition, for a differentiable map $P:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, to satisfy your equation. 
We may use complex notation and identify  $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ with $\mathbb{C}^n$, $J$ with the multiplication by $-i$, and the operators $e^{tJ}$ with multiplication by the complex scalars of modulus $1$ (*Warning*: in doing so, we still consider real differentiability, not complex differentiability, i.e. the Fréchet differential ${\rm d}P(x)$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map, not necessarily $\mathbb{C}$-linear, i.e.  not assumed  to commute with $J$). The condition then reads: $P$ is an [equivariant map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivariant_map) w.r.to the 
group action of $\mathbb{S}^1$:

$$P(\theta x)=\theta P(x)\quad\text{for all } x\in\mathbb{C}^n\setminus\{0\}  \text{ and  } \theta\in\mathbb{C} \text{ with } |\theta|=1.$$

for instance, in dimension $2$ (i.e. $n=1$) these differentiable maps $P:\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ are exactly those that in polar coordinates write as $P(r e^{it})=e^{it}\phi(r)$,  where $\phi:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable  map.

**Rmk** If one takes $J$ to be the identity map, and $P$ differentiable for any $x\ne0$, the same computation gives $P(tx)=tP(x)$ for all $t>0$ and $x\ne0$, that is, $P$ is (positively) homogeneous of degree $1$,  (equivariant w.r.to the action of homoteties) If $P$ is also assumed to be defined and differentiable at $0$, this implies $P$ linear, as observed in comments.

Comment: I  modified a bit and removed the origin from the domain, which seems a more natural setting .

Answer (score 1):

Such functions are linear. In dimension $1$, your equation means
$$P(x)=P'(x)x$$
Solving this differential equation we obtain $P(x)=cx$. Now in arbitrary dimension, your condition can be written as
$$x_j\sum_j \partial P/\partial x_j=P$$
for each coordinate $P$, which means that $P$ is a homogeneous function of degree $1$,
by Euler's theorem,

http://www.its.caltech.edu/~kcborder/Notes/EulerHomogeneity.pdf

Comment: This is false. In 2D, take $P_i(x,y)=x^2/(x+y)$. It satisfies my condition, but it is not linear. Moreover, along any line $y=\alpha x$, it is linear, but not over the plane $x-y$.

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli Your example is not differentiable at the origin (which was implicitly assumed in the question). If  $P:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ (or $P:X\to Y$ between normed spaces, more in general)  is homogeneous of degree $1$ **and** differentiable at the origin, the remainder $P(x)-dP(0)x$ is also $1$-homogeneous, and since it is $o(x)$ for $x\to0$, it is identically zero, that is $P=dP(0)$  **is** linear.

Comment: @Doriano Brogioli: I did not understand your example: you have a subscript $i$ in the left hand side, but there is no $i$ in the right hand side. Where is the map from $R^2$ to $R^2$?

Comment: As highlighted in the comments to the question, the problem can be posed for each component. For writing a 2D version we can take $P_1(x,y)=P_2(x,y)=x^2/(x+y)$, two equal components. My example is not defined in 0, so I must admit that you are right. Rigorously... but the more general meaning of my question was better answered by the connection to homogeneous functions.

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli Your original question talked of a function from $R^n$ to $R^n$ and the usual understanding among analysts is that "from $X$ to $Y$" means that the domain of the function is $X$. Maybe you had a slightly different question in mind, which could be asked separately?

Comment: No, it is this. $X=Y=\mathbb{R}^n$. In my example above, the domain is in $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. couples of numbers $x,y$. The image is (possibly a subset of) $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. the couple of numbers $P_1, P_2$. Could you explain better where is the misunderstanding?

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli I don't see that your example has domain $\mathbb R^2$. It's undefined along the line $x=-y$.

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli: the misunderstanding that Yemon Choi had in mind (I guess?) was that, when one writes "$f$ is a map from $X$ to $Y$", one usually means that $f$ is defined on the WHOLE space $X$.

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct! Rigorously, my question asked about functions defined everywhere in $\mathbb{R}^n$. So, rigorously, the functions $P$ are linear. However, I feel that the most complete answer was the one given in the comments to the question, which captures the more general meaning: any $P_i$ is a homogeneous function. This implies: either $P_i$ is linear, or it is not defined everywhere in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thank you all for your contribution.

Comment: Homogeneous function of degree $1$ can be defined everywhere on $R^n$, for example $x^3/(x^2+y^2)$, but they are usually not differentiable at the origin.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350785/a-function-in-mathbbrn-is-equal-to-its-linearization-in-each-point#comment879142_350794) function is not defined at the origin.

Comment: @LSpice: Why not? It is $0$ at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the equation for a homogeneous degree one function; see "Euler's homogeneous function theorem".

If such a function is differentiable at the origin, then it has to be linear.

Comment: Thank you and all the others who contributed, in particular @Alexandre Eremenko. Do you have any suggestion about the "symplectic version", maybe inspired by the analogy with the homogeneous functions?